# stored procedure (Visual Studio ASP.Net 2005 C#)

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I made a stored procedure called "usp_insertempdata" that inserts data into the database table called "Employee", so i executed it and when i save data i brings an exception:
"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
Any help please!
here is my code

```
    SqlConnection _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection ( );
string strConnectionString = "";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ( );

strConnectionString = @"Server='bisweb\bisweb';Database=x_kgabo;Trusted_Connection=true;";

Int32 rowsAffected;

List<object> lstParams = new List<object> ( );

cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchEmployeeNo", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchEmployeeNo" ].Value = txtEmployeeNumber.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchSurname", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchSurname" ].Value = txtSurname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchFirstName" ].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchPosition", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchPosition" ].Value = txtPosition.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchIdNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchIdNumber" ].Value = txtIdNumber.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchGender", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchGender" ].Value = drpdwnGender.SelectedItem.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchRace", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchRace" ].Value = drpdwnRace.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchEmail" ].Value = txtEmail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@iBranchNo", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@iBranchNo" ].Value = txtBranchNo.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@bHasMentor", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@bHasMentor" ].Value = drpdwnMentor.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchMentorName", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchMentorName" ].Value = txtMentorName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@vchMentorStaffNo", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@vchMentorStaffNo" ].Value = txtMentorStaffNo.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@dtMentorDate", SqlDbType.VarChar ) );
cmd.Parameters [ "@dtMentorDate" ].Value = calMentorDate.SelectedDate;

cmd.CommandText = "usp_insertempdata";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = _SqlConnection;

_SqlConnection.Open ( );

rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ( );

_SqlConnection.Close ( );

try
{
    _SqlConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
    _SqlConnection.Open ( );

}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    //throw  ex;
    messagefunctions ( );
    lblError.Text = "There was a problem inserting a record into the database, please consult with systems administrators " + ex.Message.ToString ( );
}
finally
{
    if ( _SqlConnection != null )
        _SqlConnection.Close ( );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be that you are assigning the connection string after you called ExecuteNonQuery and after your first call to Open. The second call is nonsense.
The correct sequence would be:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_SqlConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
cmd.Connection = _SqlConnection;

try
{
    _SqlConnection.Open ( );

    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ( );

    _SqlConnection.Close ( );
}
```

Comment: The connection string is never passed to the SqlConnection object, though the connection is opened, (attempted to be), prior to the Exec call on cmd

Comment: Take a look 3 lines above the try{ statement

Comment: What's there? Certainly not the assignment of the connection string. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your connection string:

```
strConnectionString = @"Server='bisweb\bisweb';Database=x_kgabo;Trusted_Connection=true;";
```

(btw: I believe you shouldn't be using any single quotes around the server name)

but you're never assigning it to your `SqlConnection`!

Change your code around so that the connection string will actually be used in your `SqlConnection` object! Also - always put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(....) { .... }` blocks....

```
string strConnectionString = @"Server=bisweb\bisweb;Database=x_kgabo;Trusted_Connection=true;";
string storedProcName = "usp_insertempdata";

using(SqlConnection _SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, _SqlConnection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Int32 rowsAffected;

    ......
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer is clear and straight forward,i understood what you are saying and i highly appreciate it. so i changed my code as you said and i got another exception: Error converting data type varchar to bit. May you please help on how to fix this.

Comment: @kgabo: that would indicate that one of your parameters probably is of type `BIT` in SQL Server, and you pass in a `VARCHAR` value that cannot be converted to a `BIT`. Check your parameters!

Comment: Thank you Marc, i checked my parameters and find that i did not use the correct syntax (_________.checked) to get a value from a CheckBox. My problem is solved.Thank you very much and all of you who tried to help me...Cheers